# Kafka concurrent listener but handling messages containig specific value in single thread (one by one)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I need help with kafka concurrency. I have concurrent listener in my spring boot app:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      concurrency: 2
```

And consumer consumes messages for specific client. And now i need to make the messages for single client be handled one after another, because inside i update a single document in mongo, and I get an OptimistickLockingException. Is there a way to achieve this behavious?

Same thing visualised:

```
event1 - customer1
event2 - customer1
event3 - customer2
```

and the threads are consuming like:

```
thread1 - event1 - customer1
thread2 - event2 - customer1 (OptimistickLockingException)
thread2 - event3 - customer2
```

and I need like that:

```
thread1 - event1 - customer1
thread2 - event3 - customer2
thread1 - event2 - customer1 (or thread2 if it finished first.)
```

so this is an exception in concurrency. Is it possible?

Regards